# How to clone sub-directory inside another sub-directory?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules, git-clone

Have one repository in Gitlab like this folder tree:

```
somerepo
  ├─ innerrepo1
  └─ innerrepo2
```

**somerepo** is the main repository. The others are sub-directories. Is it possible to clone *innerrepo1* inside *innerrepo2*? If yes, how to do it?

I have no idea how to get it.
The hidden **.git** folder is inside **somerepo**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add it as a submodule:

```
git submodule [--quiet] add [<options>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
```

Example (using *master* branch and dummy GitHub links):

```
git submodule add master --name innerrepo1 https://github.com/bla_bla_bla/innerrepo1.git innerrepo2/innerrepo1
```

This will add the following entry in the file: "*/somerepo/.gitmodules*":

```
[submodule "innerrepo1"]
    path = innerrepo2/innerrepo1
    url = https://github.com/bla_bla_bla/innerrepo1.git
```

For more info see: [Git-Tools-Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) and [git-submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).